# How to use Material Design 3 web without NPM?

Tags: html, web-development, web-design

I've been using Material Design Lite (1.3) for a long time. Now I would like to use Material Design
3. (sporting this code which is still Material Design 1.3).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.orange-yellow.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
```

But I am using a Chromebook with admin lock. Therefore it is not possible to build Material Design 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use esm.run:

```html
<script src="https://esm.run/@material/web/all.js" type="module"></script>
```

Example:

```html
<label>
  Material 3
  <md-checkbox checked></md-checkbox>
</label>

<md-outlined-button>Back</md-outlined-button>
<md-filled-button>Next</md-filled-button>
<script src="https://esm.run/@material/web/all.js" type="module"></script>
```

(source: https://github.com/material-components/material-web/discussions/5239#discussioncomment-7721589)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).